# Disabling unidentified host confirmation when connecting to Amazon EC2 instances using SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, boto

I am writing a script using boto and Python to automatically launch an Amazon EC2 instance and interact with it using SSH. Everything works fine except that every time I establish the connection, SSH prompts me to confirm the authenticity of the host like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'ec2-174-129-121-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com (174.129.121.25)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 26:09:bd:21:4f:55:20:3f:0d:fc:5f:cc:3e:08:30:db.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

My SSH command is:

```
ssh -i ssh2.pem root@ec2-174-129-121-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Since every EC2 instance is a new host, I have to confirm this every time, but I want an automatic script without any user input. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `-O StrictHostKeyChecking=no` and, optionally, set the `KnownHostsFile` of /dev/null (if you want to be totally insecure about things). But remember, you're bypassing security measures meant to protect you!

**edit** and probably `CheckHostIP=no` too. **`man ssh`** and see all the gory bits.

Comment: I think you also want `CheckHostIP=no`

Comment: my version of ssh doesn't have KnownHostsFile, but it does have UserKnownHostsFile.   Also, use a lower case o rather than an upper case O.

Answer (score 0):

For PuTTY and windows you can use

```
echo y | plink -pw yourpassword root@yourservername.com
```